# How to mock a server error in hapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocking, hapi.js

I have set up a hapi server as follows:

```
'use strict'
// node modules
const Hapi = require('hapi')
const Inert = require('inert')
const Path = require('path')
// server config
const server = new Hapi.Server()
const port = 4000

server.connection({
  port: port
})

// Hapi plugins
const plugins = [
  Inert
]

server.register(plugins, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }
  server.route([
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/',
      handler: (request, reply) => {
        reply.file(Path.join(__dirname, '../front/production/index.html'))
      }
    },
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/{param*}',
      handler: {
        directory: {
          path: 'front/production'
        }

      }
    }
  ])
})

module.exports = server
```

I have written tests for it, but have a problem being able to cover this line:

```
if (err) {
  throw err <----
}
```

how can I mock a server error in server.register, so far I have tried:

```
server.inject({method: 'GET', url: '/notanendpoint'}...
server.inject({method: 'NOTMETHOD', url: '/'}...
server.inject({method: 'GET', url: '/', simulate: {error: true}}...
```

I've been looking through the hapi api docs and cant work out how to cover this line, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let me know if I can add more description to my question or include what I have tried in my tests (let me know if you want to see more of my test file)

Comment: The method is registering the plugins, and the error is triggered if it can not do that job as I understand from your code, have you tried passing the wrong value instead of the plugins array ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I have already tried altering the server to include a plugin which it cant find and the line still is not run

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab but your definitely thinking down the right lines

Comment: @Dansmith You're throwing an error in the callback, it may fail: https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors

Comment: @RomanDibikhin I don't understand, if I write console.log('ERROR') on that throw err line, I cant get that to be logged anywhere (basically the line doesn't run)

Comment: The problem with throwing from a callback is that you don't know where & when your error will shoot. Even if it eventually should do this somewhere.

Comment: OK fine, let's just replace that line with console.log('error'), how can I get this to be logged somewhere

Comment: @Dansmith are you trying to _force_ the `server.register` _callback_ error to be called for a _reason_ or just in pursuit of ***100%***?